# Scala right associative methods

Tags: scala, syntax, operators, identifier, associative

I am learning Scala, and playing with right associate unapply object. I know that if the name ends with ':' then it becomes right associative. However, there seems to be some strange restrictions on the naming

e.g.
These are invalid

```
object cons: { def unapply(value: String): Option[(Char, List[Char])] = ??? }
object :_cons_: { def unapply(value: String): Option[(Char, List[Char])] = ??? }
```

These are valid

```
object cons_: { def unapply(value: String): Option[(Char, List[Char])] = ??? }
object >>: { def unapply(value: String): Option[(Char, List[Char])] = ??? }
```

So there seems to be some weirdness about mixing alpha-numeric characters and symbols in identifiers.

So basically, I want to have a descriptive name i.e. 'cons' and still have right associativity. Also, I would like my operator to be symetric for aesthetic reasons :-), so I dont really like `cons_:`
Is there a way to make something associate to the right without using a colon? Or any other suggestions to achieve this?

`:_cons_:` seems to be the closest, but, for some reason the identifier can't start with ':' and have alphanumerics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (section 1.1):

> There are three ways to form an identifier. First, an identifier can
>   start with a letter which can be followed by an arbitrary sequence of
>   letters and digits. This may be followed by underscore ‘_’ characters
>   and another string composed of either letters and digits or of
>   operator characters. Second, an identifier can start with an operator
>   character followed by an arbitrary sequence of operator characters.
>   The preceding two forms are called *plain* identifiers. Finally, an
>   identifier may also be formed by an arbitrary string between
>   back-quotes (host systems may impose some restrictions on which
>   strings are legal for identifiers). The identifier then is composed of
>   all characters excluding the backquotes themselves.

So it looks like you're out of luck—if your identifier starts with a `:` it can't contain non-operator characters. Note, though, that you *can* write the following (which isn't intended to do anything meaningful—just to demonstrate the syntax):

```
scala> class X { def `:cons:`(i: Int) = i }
defined class X

scala> val x = new X
x: X = X@6a665da6

scala> 1 `:cons:` x
res1: Int = 1
```

The method name still ends with a colon, so you get the right associativity you're looking for.

Comment: Great! I didn't know about using back ticks to allow arbitrary identifiers. Thanks

Comment: The last character isn't a backquote, it's a colon. The quote characters in a quoted identifier no more become a part of the identifier than the quote characters in a string literal do. The last character of the string denoted by the string literal `"Hello"` isn't `"`, it's `o`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Wow, that was some incredible misreading on my part—the "excluding" is right there. In my defense it was early here and I was still a little bitter about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17863794/334519). I've edited to remove my surprise that the backtick approach works.